# Facebook video Upload error

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

Facebook video upload error: i'm using the combination of the old
and the new API/SDK from the link https://github.com/zoul/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/efb4b44fad333f8daa70a517bb5328b9352320df
and i m getting session id properly in the video Upload class

```
- (void) startUploadWithURL: (NSURL*) movieURL params: (NSDictionary*) userParams delegate: (id ) delegate
{
    apiKey = @"5c009deec3b253bef6fe6cdd97e86b3f";
    appSecret = @"218421681dfb46043bed3dd25a03bbce";

    if ([self sessionID] == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to retrieve session key from the access token.");
        return;
    }
    printf(" \n\n session id == %s",[[self sessionID] UTF8String]);

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:userParams];
    [params setObject:@"1.0" forKey:@"v"];
        [params setObject:@"facebook.video.upload" forKey:@"method"];
        [params setObject:[self sessionID] forKey:@"session_key"];
        [params setObject:apiKey forKey:@"api_key"];
        [params setObject:[self signatureForParams:params] forKey:@"sig"];
       [params setObject:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL] forKey:[movieURL lastPathComponent]];
        [[FBRequest getRequestWithParams:params httpMethod:@"POST" delegate:delegate requestURL:kAPIURL] connect];

}
```

its returning the wrong result and not uploading video to the Facebook

Answer (score 0):

Without using graph api you can upload videos to facebook.login facebook and go to this [link](http://www.facebook.com/mobile/). there you will get a id like xyz@m.facebook.com .just mail your videos to this mail id.you can use a MFmailcompossor to compose mail from your app.

Hope this help

Comment: hey @Sat --V can Shake The World -- this sounds cool, but can u please elaborate it more.